# Iphone app that needs to scrape a website once every day

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-scraping, web-crawler

So I'm making an iphone application that needs to scrape a website once everyday.

What I'm going to scrape is a table of upcoming games for that same day for a soccer division. Thats why i need the app to scrape from the same page and same table once everyday to keep the upcoming games updated.

I was referred to import.io but they didn't have something like a schedule re-crawl.

I would love to get some ideas and tips to how i should do this since I'm stuck now.

Comment: You will need to keep track of when you last did an update. Then I would look at getting a copy of the HTML of the page and see if you can parse down to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at https://www.kimonolabs.com/

I played around with the service a while back and was impressed with how easy it way to set up. They have a "free" option so long as the APIs you create are not private.

Oh, and I agree with Paul, screen scraping is not something the iOS client should be doing. Too fragile, and when (not if) something breaks, you will need to go through an Apple review process to fix it.

Comment: Wonderful suggestion. I really love how easy and powerful this tool is. Thank you so much!

@picciano

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like something an app should do, your server should do it (so that the scraping is only performed once), and your clients can retrieve it from your server.  That also means you could send out push notifications for important fixtures etc.  Maybe that's what you meant, anyway.

If it's on the server you can just setup a scheduler (in Java, for example) to run once every x hours (probably a smaller number than 24 assuming you don't know when the website is to be updated).  Then your app can just get the latest list of fixtures from your server on startup, pull-to-refresh, etc.  Presumably someone will open your app, look at the fixtures, then come out of your app - so it doesn't seem like you need to cover the case where someone is in your app all day, but if you did you could use NSTimer to run every x minutes after the initial on-startup server call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I will get on right to it. I just have to pick the right server now. Im thinking about picking either Kimonolabs or amazon web services. Don't know which one would suit me the best. @paul macrory